# What is the 'Zzz' complication on Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

It is shown here in an image from a [Wired article](https://www.wired.com/2015/04/the-apple-watch/) on the watch before it came out. [image]

Comment: Possibly a [sleep tracker app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sleep-pulse-2-motion-sleep/id1005468883?mt=8)?

Comment: I'd guess it's the iOS 10 bedtime feature in the Clock app? @Allan All the others are first-party, it would be odd to include a separate app in there imo

Comment: @grgarside - I agree, but all we have is a pic of a screenshot from an unspecified Wired mag article.  All we can do is speculate.

Comment: @Allan Of course, just saying in case you hadn't noticed

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the link to article and mention it was before the watch came out so it is definitely not third party. Probably a feature that got canned but I wanted to double check with everyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the alarm complication if you choose to snooze an alarm.

[image: Snooze complication on Apple Watch 38 mm]